# Django Admin Static Files No Longer Working: "Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Tags: python, django, static

I am able to create a Django Project and and my admin site works fine initially. After I create an app, register it, setup static files, the **Django Admin** page actually starts complaining that I failed to give it static files at all. *(Something I don't consider myself to be on the hook for)*

So when I hit: http://127.0.0.1/admin (like I always do), somewhere in the timeline, I face an error that says:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/login/
Invalid block tag on line 4: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Okay so that seems like a silly question, but why am I being asked if I registered the static tag? What about my static tag destroyed theirs? I'm not even sure which files I should be looking at right now.

In `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'myapp',
]

DEBUG = True
```

... *snip - irrelevant stuff*

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ‘myapp', 'static'),
]
```

The file that is *breaking down* isn't mine to edit. It's the admin one. Where should I be looking? I should also note that my own app also no longer is able to load it's static files and returns the same error now.

TL;DR: "How can one accidentally disable all static files for the development site? How does one restore that functionality?"

---

Update 2018-09-10:

I shipped the whole application from my Windows 10 laptop to my Linux machine and the application booted perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04. I've made no file changes, other than regenerating my `virtualenv` from the same requirements file.

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate. 1) that’s an older version of Django. 2) that is pertaining to their app, not the admin one. How can a user affect the admin one?

Comment: If I applied this recommendation to the Django admin site, it assumes that what the nice people at Django shipped me an html file that doesn’t work out of the box. I can assure you that I’ve made no changes to the admin html page directly.

Comment: I wasn't talking to myself here - the person who commented multiple times deleted them all. I'll leave my responses in case another duplicate is attempted to the same article.